# Don't enable button if not typed 11 char

Tags: jquery, html, button, input

This is the code i have in jquery, i think the logic is ok, but still i can't get it to work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#inputText').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 11)
            $('#send').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('#send').attr('disabled', true);
        })
     });
```

and this is the html, input box and button

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXX" maxlength="11"/>
<input type="button" id="send" value="submit"></input>
```

Comment: It works for me, are you sure you have jQuery included?

Comment: no, nothing happens. The button shows up anyway. I tried it at jsfiddle too but still nothing.

Comment: working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2qmre9rv/7/

Comment: @agustin i dant want it to show or hide, i just want to disable or enable

Comment: Open you javascript console and it will tell you exactly what the problem is

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('#send').attr('disabled', true);
$('#inputText').keyup(function() {
if ($(this).val().length == 11){
  $('#send').attr('disabled', false);
}else{
  $('#send').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXX" maxlength="11"/>
<input type="button" id="send" value="submit"></input>
```

Try this

Comment: it is not the jquery library problem, i have included the library

Comment: i found the problem, i had the script src and the end o the site, so they were the last to load, maybe it was conflicting... thanks anyway

Comment: Shorter code: `$('#send').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length === 11);`. I'd also suggest to `trim` the value before checking length.